# Find amount of benzoic acid in dissolution

Tags: physical-chemistry, stoichiometry

> Solubility of benzoic acid in water at $\pu{0^\circ C}$ is $\pu{1.7 g/L}$ and given the fact that $\pu{37 mL}$ was used to dissolve $\pu{1 g}$ of benzoic acid. How much of the benzoic acid would be left over given these conditions?

I have tried using $c = m/vM$ to convert $\pu{1.7 g/L}$ to a form given the $\pu{1 g}$ and the $\pu{37 mL}$ actually used. How would I find out how much is left over?

Answer (score 1):

$\pu{0.037L}$ of water dissolves $0.037\times \pu{1.7g}$ of benzoic acid at $\pu{0^\circ C}$ = $\pu{0.0629g}$.

Therefore $1 - 0.0629 = \pu{0.9371g}$ benzoic acid remains undissolved